# What am I doing wrong with my SSRS textbox expression?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, expression

I am creating an RDLC report for donations. I have `dataset1` which includes an `SVC` table and a `DOR` table. In my expression, I am able to obtain the dollar amounts in the `SVC` table, however, I have been unable to get the organization names from the `DOR` table. What I am trying to do:

1. Look at each record, identified by `SVC_IDNUM`
2. Get values from donation fields (example `SVC_DN01PY, SVC_DN02PY, SVC_DN03PY`)
3. Get value from `SVC_DONCOD` (donation code) and match to the `DOR_ORGNUM` code and get the corresponding `DOR_ORGNAM` (organization name).

The donation amounts works, but the organization name does not. I am not well versed with SSRS and have been searching for a solution. What am I missing or doing wrong?

I have been trying to use `Join`, `LookupSet` to try and achieve this.

```
="Donations: " & Join(LookupSet(Fields!SVC_IDNUM.Value,Fields!SVC_IDNUM.Value,
 IIF(Fields!SVC_DONCOD.Value = Fields!DOR_ORGNUM.Value, Fields!DOR_ORGNAM.Value &" ", " ") & IIF(Fields!SVC_DN01PY.Value > 0, Fields!SVC_DN01PY.Value &" ", " ") &
 IIF(Fields!SVC_DONCOD.Value = Fields!DOR_ORGNUM.Value, Fields!DOR_ORGNAM.Value &" ", " ") & IIF(Fields!SVC_DN02PY.Value > 0, Fields!SVC_DN02PY.Value &" ", " ") &
 IIF(Fields!SVC_DONCOD.Value = Fields!DOR_ORGNUM.Value, Fields!DOR_ORGNAM.Value &" ", " ") & IIF(Fields!SVC_DN03PY.Value > 0, Fields!SVC_DN03PY.Value &" ", " "),"DataSet1"))
```

I have also included my SQL query for DataSet1. It is a lengthy query because there is a lot of info required for the report.

```
string query1 = "SELECT FJSSVBAT.SVB_BATNBR, FORMAT(FJSSVBAT.SVB_CHKDAT,'MM/dd/yyyy'),
FJSWHEEL.WHL_IDNUM, FJSWHEEL.WHL_FSTNAM, FJSWHEEL.WHL_MIDNAM, FJSWHEEL.WHL_LSTNAM, 
FJSWHEEL.WHL_SUFFIX, FJSWHEEL.WHL_ADDR1, FJSWHEEL.WHL_ADDR2, FJSWHEEL.WHL_CITY,
FJSWHEEL.WHL_STATE, FJSWHEEL.WHL_ZIPCDE, FJSWHEEL.WHL_SUBPNL, FJSWHEEL.WHL_SELCNT, 
FJSSVCTL.SVC_CHKNBR, FORMAT(FJSSVCTL.[SVC_CHKDAT],'MM/dd/yyyy'), FJSSVCTL.SVC_BATNBR, 
FJSSVCTL.SVC_IDNUM, FJSSVCTL.SVC_ONEWAY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_TRVPAY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_REGPAY, 
FJSSVCTL.SVC_HGHPAY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_HGHPY2, FJSSVCTL.SVC_HGHPY3, FJSSVCTL.SVC_PRKPAY, 
FJSSVCTL.SVC_SBSPAY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_MSCPAY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_TOTPAY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_JURPAY, 
FJSSVCTL.SVC_DONPAY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DONCOD, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN01PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN02PY, 
FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN03PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN04PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN05PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN06PY, 
FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN07PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN08PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN09PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN10PY, 
FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN11PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN12PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN13PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN14PY, 
FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN15PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN16PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN17PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN18PY, 
FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN19PY, FJSSVCTL.SVC_DN20PY, DONORG.DOR_ORGNUM, DONORG.DOR_ORGNAM,
FJSSVDTL.*, FJSDSCTL.DS_DSTNM1, FJSDSCTL.DS_DSTNM2 FROM FJSSVBAT JOIN FJSSVCTL ON 
FJSSVBAT.SVB_BATNBR = @BatchNumber JOIN FJSWHEEL ON FJSSVCTL.SVC_IDNUM =
FJSWHEEL.WHL_IDNUM JOIN FJSSVDTL ON FJSWHEEL.WHL_IDNUM = FJSSVDTL.SVD_IDNUM AND
FJSSVDTL.SVD_BATNBR = @BatchNumber FULL OUTER JOIN DONORG CROSS JOIN FJSDSCTL WHERE
(FJSSVBAT.SVB_BATNBR = @BatchNumber) AND () ORDER BY FJSSVCTL.SVC_CHKNBR";
```

With a `SVC_DONCOD.Value` of 1 and a `DOR_ORGNUM.Value` of 1, `DOR_ORNAM.Value` would be United Way and with a `SVC_DN01PY.Value` of $7.16
The results in the textbox should be United Way $7.16. This is a screenshot of part of the report and this is one record of many on the report. The red line indicates a single textbox which is required by my employer and must include the organization name followed by the amount donated. 
[image]

Comment: You'll probably need to show your dataset query(s) and sample output from them before anyone will be able to help. If you edit your question to include these I'm sure you get better responses.

Comment: Alan is correct, this expression is incredibly complicated and I'm guessing there's a much easier way.  The queries being used and some data as it's laid out in the table would be great. Honestly, I'm thinking you could do this without the `Join` and `LookupSet` as these sorts of concatenated fields would be better off in their own cells/textboxes.  You're basically trying to just cram everything into one expression when SSRS is good at repeating the same expression with multiple rows of data.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the requested info.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Lookupset()` expression is wrong. Depending on what relationship you have, you can display your data with a `Lookup()` (for a 1:1 relationship) and a `LookupSet()` for a 1:n relationship. I think with this example you should be able to get your report working. I am not exactly sure how your tables are but I am assuming something like this:

**1:1 Relationship**

```
'Dataset1

 SVC_DONCOD1   Amount
     1          20€
     2          30€

'Dataset2

SVC_DONCOD2   CompanyName
    1          Test1
    2          Test2
```

If you put your `Dataset2` in a tablix you can display `SVC_DONCOD2` and `CompanyName`. To display the `Amount` as well, add the following expression in the detail textbox:

```
=Lookup(Fields!SVC_DONCOD2.Value, Fields!SVC_DONCOD1.Value, Fields!Amount.Value, "Dataset1")
```

The result:

```
 SVC_DONCOD2   Amount   CompanyName
     1          20€        Test1
     2          30€        Test2
```

**1:n Relationship**

```
 SVC_DONCOD1   Amount
     1          20€
     2          30€
     1          10€
     1          10€

'Dataset2

SVC_DONCOD2   CompanyName
    1          Test1
    2          Test2
```

Again put `Dataset2` in a tablix, this time add the following expression:

```
=LookupSet(Fields!SVC_DONCOD2.Value, Fields!SVC_DONCOD1.Value, Fields!Amount.Value, "Dataset1")
```

The result:

```
 SVC_DONCODE2   CompanyName  Amount
     1            Test1       20€
                              10€
                              10€
     2            Test2
```

Note:

If your key consist of two fields, just concat them like this:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Dataset1Key1.Value & Fields!Dataset1Key2.Value, Fields!Dataset2Key1.Value & Fields!Dataset2Key2.Value, Fields!Disaplay.Value, "Dataset2")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have everything in 1 dataset, should I actually be using 2 separate datasets?

Comment: If you have everything what you need in one Dataset then just use one, its always better then two.

Comment: I'll take a look at the relationship. So far everything else I've tried is failing on me.